# Making my Node app accessible to the Internet from a local machine

Tags: node.js, http, server, webserver, portforwarding

OK so I know I can use cloud hosting and I've done so before but I am doing a demo and I want my node app to be on my local machine but accessible from the internet. Here is how I start the server in the server file

```
const port = 8080;
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Next I set up port forwarding on my Xfinity gateway such that both port 80 and port 8080 point to my desktop. I know I am connecting to the right device because SSH works from outside of my network on port 22. However when I enter **[public IP]:8080** I am unable to receive a response. The only time I receive a response is when I enter **10.0.0.58:8080** which refers to my internal network. Why is this??? [image]

Comment: Consider that you may have a firewall (hardware or software) blocking the 8080 port.

Comment: @JonathanWilson I just turned the firewall in my gateway off completely. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like ngrok to do the same thing. It's really easy to setup and I found it really stable. 
Give it a go https://ngrok.com
After installing you can simply forward ports like
    ngrok http 8080